# Firebase query retrieve data from several children and do math

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to do a query to my firebase to calculate an average of some entries.

I feel like i did't completely understand this, and feel like I am fumbling in the dark.

My code to try to retrieve the data is like this:

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int year = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String dateString = year + checkDigit(month) + checkDigit(day);
        Long date = Long.valueOf(dateString);
        Long alongweekago = date - 6;
        String aweekago = alongweekago.toString();
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userId);

        Query lastSevenDays = mDatabase.orderByKey().endAt(aweekago).limitToLast(7);

        lastSevenDays.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                final String lastsevendates = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                Log.w(TAG, lastsevendates);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

my datastructure is like this:

[image]

What I want to do is retrieve the "efficiency" key from the last 7 dates, and calculate an average on them. I am just not sure about the best way to do this. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Regards
Rune

Comment: If calculating the average is the only thing you're doing with the data, then you needn't store a separate dates node. However, if you ever want to deal with only the dates, and then show what happened on one exact date (on click of an item on a list for example), then the extra dates node would be useful

Comment: I do exactly what you say here, so thats why I have the list of dates. :)

Answer (score 2):

While structuring your database, you must try to make it such that a query gives you all the data that you want to show on screen. For example, if you want to show the efficiency of the last 7 days, you can do that as you add every day, rather than calculate it later, and then just query for it.

```
"userId":{
  "weekEfficiency":{
    "average": 50
    "prevEfficiency":20
  }
  "20160710":{...}
  "20160711":{...}
}
```

In this structure, whenever you add a new day, do something like this

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userId);
mDatabase.child(dateString).setValue(whateverYouSetRightNow);

Double average = null;
mDatabase.child("weekEfficiency").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    Map<String, String> data = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue;
                    double efficiency = Double.parseDouble(data.get("average"));
                    double prevEfficiency = Double.parseDouble(data.get("prevEfficiency"));
                    average = (efficiency*7-prevEfficiency+efficiencyToday)/7;
                    setAverage(average)
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                }
            });
```

And Here's the method setAverage:

```
private void setAverage(double average) {
    mDatabase.child("weekEfficiency").child("prevEfficiency").setValue(efficiencyToday);
    mDatabase.child("weekEfficiency").child("average").setValue(average);
}
```

Comment: I just realised this might be entirely useless to you

Comment: It is not useless at all, it is in fact exactly what I need I think. I will try it. :)

Comment: I was wondering.. If you implemented this, how you do it for the first 7 days?

Comment: I am figuring that out as we speak. Thinking of doing a check if data exists at the node, and if not I set a starting efficiency of 50. Only solution I could think of.

Comment: Ok, I did nearly what I said. I check to see if data exists, and if not, I set todays efficiency as the previous one.

Comment: But that wouldn't give you the average on the second day

Comment: The starting with fifty seemed fine.. as long as you don't call it average.. but if you really want an average even for the first 7 days, you have to store it (maybe in just one string with spaces so you can split it and calculate an average) and use what I said in the answer after you get 7 days of data

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you should not have a `dates` node inside it like this, it's not the right way to order nodes.

Second `endAt()` should b used where u are sure that that node actually exist
and if u are searching for dates you should use `datasnapshot.getKey()` instead of `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()` and would fire keys one after other.

For `efficeincy` you can use `hashMap`

```
 Map<String, String> data = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
String Efficency=data.get("efficency");
```

You also can use Model Class To retrieve all data into it.

Comment: He's not searching for dates. He's checking to see if he gets all the data for 7 days intact. Also, why is it a bad idea to store a separate dates node?

Comment: because if you are putting something different inside a specific list of items that is just not a good practice that may create problems in further things.

Comment: Problems like what?

Comment: If you know that there is a dates node, and if you set up your security rules properly, I don't see how this is a problem because you can use startAt() and endAt(). But I guess creating a separate node with "datesWithDetails" or something seems better

Comment: I have moved my dates node to a separate location now. I ran into the problem with queries earlier today. 

Comment: that's where I wanted to help u.